# Segue from CollectionViewCell to Another View Controller Passing IndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to pass the indexPath of a cell tapped in a UICollectionView to another view controller. I can't seem to get the indexPath of what was selected and segue it to the next view controller

**I get this error:** "Could not cast value of type Post to PostCell"

**View Controller #1:**

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PostCell {
            cell.configureCell(post)
        }
        return cell
    } 
}

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedPost: Post!
        selectedPost = posts[indexPath.row]
        performSegueWithIdentifier("PostDetailVC", sender: selectedPost)
    }

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PostDetailVC" {

      //Error here: Could not cast value of Post to PostCell
       if let selectedIndex = self.collection.indexPathForCell(sender as! PostCell){
           print(selectedIndex)
        }

        if let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? PostDetailVC {
            if let selectedPost = sender as? Post {
                print(selectedIndex)
                detailsVC.post = selectedPost
                detailsVC.myId = self.myId!
                detailsVC.indexNum = selectedIndex
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**View Controller #2:**

```
var indexNum: NSIndexPath!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   print(indexNum)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a `Post` instance which doesn't match the expected `PostCell` instance.

I recommend to pass the index path

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("PostDetailVC", sender: indexPath)
}
```

---

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PostDetailVC" {
       guard let selectedIndexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath,
                 detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? PostDetailVC else { return }
       print(selectedIndexPath)

       let selectedPost = posts[selectedIndexPath.row]
       detailsVC.post = selectedPost
       detailsVC.myId = self.myId!
       detailsVC.indexNum = selectedIndexPath
   }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I definitely understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `Post` and not a `PostCell` as `sender`.  You don't need that anyway, as the collectionView keeps track of selected items.

Try this:

```
if let selectedIndex = self.collection.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first {
    print(selectedIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are giving argument which has type of `Post` and you are trying to cast it as `PostCell`. Which will not work.